# Website with a lot of Images and very slow

Tags: image, performance, web

My website in general has a lot of images to load. But my homepage actually has very few images, yet everytime I test my website through website speed tests, it tries to load all my images on my entire website. Why doesn't it just load the images on the home page? Why do all my images on all my subpages try to load on the initial home page?

Comment: You must have some HTML, CSS, or JavaScript on the page that is telling it to load those images. Otherwise the browser couldn't know they exist.

Comment: Can we have a link to your page (only so we will be able to help you)?

Comment: www.finelineperspectives.com; thank you. I have no known javascript or html that is telling it to load all my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the top of your style.css file, you have a rule that apparently preloads 130 images from your portfolio folder:

```
body:after
{
content: url(../images/portfolio/d-b-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-8-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-b-8-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-8-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-8-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-9-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-9-h.png)  url(../images/portfolio/d-c-10-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-10-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-11-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-c-11-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-cs-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-8-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-8-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-9-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-9-h.png)  url(../images/portfolio/d-p-10-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-10-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-p-11-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-8-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-8-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-9-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-9-h.png)  url(../images/portfolio/d-r-10-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-10-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-r-11-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-v-7-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-1-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-1-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-2-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-3-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-4-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-4-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-5-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-6-h.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-6-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-7-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/d-w-7-h.png)  url(../images/portfolio/m-b-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-c-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-cs-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-cs-5-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-p-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-r-3-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-v-2-bw.png) url(../images/portfolio/m-w-3-bw.png);
display: none;
}
```

Seems like you should either remove that or trim it down or move it to the portfolio pages so it isn't loaded unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you! I will see what should be removed!